# How to disable Geoloc on leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in a c# app, and I have some trouble on certain devices:

On Samsung Galaxy S4, The map is automatically centered on the localisation of the perosn, but I don't want to!

Otherwise, on my Sony Ericsson Xperia it doesn't make that localisation...

So when I pin Washington, if the user is in Detroit, he see detroit, and if he want to see the pin, he have to navigaot on the map to the location...

Thanks in advance for your help

Code here :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 16);


L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-key/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
detectRetina: true,    
attribution: 'Lorem Ipsum, Copiright,...',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

map.locate({ setView: false, maxZoom: 16 });

var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
                options: {
                    iconUrl: '/images/icon.png',
                    iconRetinaUrl: '/images/iconR.png',
                    iconAnchor: [45, 89]
                }
            });

// And set other stores oin the map but it doesn't help us :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you use [`L.Map.locate` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate) which set position using Geolocation API. If you don't want detect current location then you must just remove `map.locate({ setView: false, maxZoom: 16 });`. Your xperia may don't take location because it can be disabled on phone geolocation settings.

Comment: Okay @tbicr, thank you, I will check it and test it tomorrow, fine thanks :-) I came after tests to validate or ask another question haha Thanks